# Build a sum of a record attribute with CloudKit

Tags: cloudkit

I dont understand why i cant build a sum of a record attribute with a CloudKit class instead to load many many data and to calculate this in the app itself.

I can get this with NSFetchRecord, NSExpression and so on, but i cant use this objects with CloudKit classes.

This is very frustrated for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no aggregate functions in CloudKit (yet) CloudKit is a NoSQL database see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL 
You also can't query records using some kind of join. CloudKit is not meant to be used as some sort of relational database. A NoSQL database is usually chosen when you need good performance with almost unlimited scalability.